# How to correctly store SQL data in a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, jira

So I am currently writing a script to create a Jira Issue every morning with all the aborted processes of our Adeptia Broker's. All of this works, except for the part that I get the SQL data and get it into the Jira issue's description.

This is what I use to collect the SQL Server Data a the moment;

```
$SELECTQUERY = "   
    SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN, COLUMN, COLUMN, COLUMN
    FROM [$DB].[dbo].[$TABLE]
    WHERE COLUMN= 'x' AND COLUMN = 'x'
    ORDER BY COLUMN DESC
    "

try {
    # Run SQL Query
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SI -Database $DB -Username $UID -Password $PASS -Query $SELECTQUERY
    
    $test = $SELECTQUERY.output
    CreateJiraIncident -summary $summary -description $test
}

catch {
    # Error handling
    Write-Warning -Message "Well, the script didn't work..."
    break
}
```

Whenever I call the `$SELECTQUERY.output` with echo, return or Write-Host it gives me back the correct data. Does anyone know of a different way to store this data in a string so I can send it off to Jira? (No the issue isn't with the Jira part since I can add anything I want to the 'description' parameter it will show up in the Jira Issue.

I really just need a way to store all this data in a string so I can correctly send it.

Comment: Just a guess, and you don't state what actually is wrong or error, but should you not be returning a single value perhaps using `concat(column, column, column...)`?

Comment: You can assign the result of the query to a PowerShell variable by doing `$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd ...`. Then you can access the data by doing `$result.COLUMN`. Side note, i hope $TABLE isn't a parameter to the script, i would be wary of SQL Injection.

Comment: They're just some made up names, this example has no actual names in it. Thanks for the warning though haha.

I'll also check out your idea!

Comment: So you basically want to get the results, which is a table (with columns and rows) and put that in a Jira comment?

Comment: Basically, yes. I just find it odd that I can add anything to the variables $description and it will be added to the Jira Issue, but when I try and fill it with the output of my Invoke-Sqlcmd, then it doesn't work :/

Comment: You need to "serialise" your dataset object into a string. If you want to get fancy you can try and format it as a table in Jira. You could try `ConvertTo-Html` for example.